# How do I replace a comma to "\," in a string using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a string in which I need to replace "," with "\," using shell script. I thought I can use `sed` to do this but no luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that without `sed`:

```
string="${string/,/\\,}"
```

To replace all occurrences of "," use this:

```
string="${string//,/\\,}"
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="Hello,World"
string="${string/,/\\,}"
echo "$string"
```

Output:

```
Hello\,World
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the back slash `\/`
I'm not sure what your input is but this will work:

```
echo "teste,test" |sed  's/,/\\/g'
```

---

output:

```
teste\test
```

---

Demo:
http://ideone.com/JUTp1X

---

If the string is on a file, you can use:

```
sed -i 's/,/\//g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but note that the OP wants `,` to be replaced with `\,`, not just `\ `.